# can't transform a data frame with duplicate names mutate() function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Yesterday when I tried to use `mutate()` function to recode some values in a specific column, everything was fine.
But suddenly, I run these codes again today, it returns errors from the line with `mutate()` function：

```
 Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names.
```

Backtrace:

1. EVS_recode %>% mutate_at(c("C001"), ~na_if(., -1))
2. dplyr::mutate_at(., c("C001"), ~na_if(., -1))
3. dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(.tbl, !!!funs)
4. dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, ..., caller_env = caller_env())
5. DataMask$new(.data, caller_env)
6. dplyr:::initialize(...)

here are the codes I used which work perfectly yesterday

```
#recode the 1 in column C001 to be 5, 2 to be 4#

EVS_recode <- EVS_recode %>% mutate(C001= recode(C001, '1' = 5, '2'= 4))

#recode the -1,-2,-4,-5 values to be NA in column C001#

EVS_recode <- EVS_recode %>% mutate_at(c('C001'), ~na_if(.,-1))

EVS_recode <- EVS_recode %>% mutate_at(c('C001'), ~na_if(.,-2))

EVS_recode <- EVS_recode %>% mutate_at(c('C001'), ~na_if(.,-4))

EVS_recode <- EVS_recode %>% mutate_at(c('C001'), ~na_if(.,-5))
```

This is my first time to have such large scale of codes not working related to `mutate()`.
Could someone help me or has the similar problem when using mutate() ?

Thanks for your time to read this!
It would be very helpful if someone can give me a hint.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have two variables with the same name in your dataframe, hence the error.

You could try using `case_when()` to achieve this in one go and maybe it resolves the error

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble::tibble(C001 = c(-1,1,-2,3, -4, -5, 5,5,3,2,1,-1))
df %>% 
  mutate(across(C001, ~ case_when(
    C001 == 1 ~ 5,
    C001 == 2 ~ 4,
    C001 %in% c(-1, -2, -4,-5) ~ NA_real_, 
    TRUE ~ C001
  )))
```

You could also use `replace`

```
df %>% mutate(across(C001, ~replace(., . %in% c(-1, -2, -4,-5), NA)))
```

Comment: thanks but the replace() function still gives me the same error  "can't transform a data frame with duplicate names"

Answer (score 0):

Try df <- data.frame(df) before your code.

Comment: Please put suggestions to try something in comments. If you're confident (and only then) that it solves the problem, pose it as an answer, with some explanation.